# Send function parameters with fetch api

Tags: javascript, php, post, fetch, blob

I want to save a generated blob pdf with a filename to the server using fetch api. I managed to save the pdf but how i can send the variable fileName.

JS code :

```
function uploadBlob (blob, fileName) { 
   fetch(`http://localhost/upload.php`, {
     method:"POST",
     body:blob
   }).then(response => console.log(response.text()))
}
```

upload.php :

```
<?php    
    $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/pdf/generatedpdfwithfilenanme.pdf", $data );
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

am not sure about php but javascript side should be correct as i have experiance with it

```
function uploadBlob (blob, fileName) { 
   fetch(`http://localhost/upload.php?fileName=${encodeURIComponent(fileName)}`, {
     method:"POST",
     body:blob
   }).then(response => console.log(response.text()))
}
```

and in php

```
<?php    
    $fileName = $_GET["fileName"];
    $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/pdf/" . $fileName /*. ".pdf" */, $data );
?>
```

### edit

i had a bug in code, accessing wrong url key, its now fixed

Comment: Unless the filename contains characters that can't be part of a URI. You need `encodeURIComponent`. Also, including both GET and POST parameters on a POST is slightly iffy. :-)

Comment: @levy - Again, the above needs to properly URI-encode the filename: `...?fileName=${encodeURIComponent(fileName)}`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File) constructor around the `Blob` to add a name to it. The `File` constructor is basically an extended `Blob` with some extra properties, like a `name` property.

```
function uploadBlob (blob, fileName) {
  const file = new File(blob, fileName);
  fetch(`http://localhost/upload.php`, {
    method: "POST",
    body: file
  }).then(response => console.log(response.text()))
}
```